# Create Canvas and continuous line

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to create a canvas that can be placed on a secure website, the canvas has numbered points on it  and I need to be able to draw a continuous line between the points the line also needs to be timed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sounds like a great project. What code have you written and where did you get stuck? What is your question? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need guidance in writing a great, answerable question.

Comment: also, what do you mean by the line needs to be "timed"?

Comment: I have been looking around on SO for code and found code that I think will work. This is the link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Haelle/v6tfp2e1 .  However, I am new to this and my website uses Fusion Builder. The first problem is how to get this working on my website. The second problem is how measure the time the user takes to draw the line from mouse down to mouse up, then this time needs to be placed in a database against the users name. Thanks for the assistance.